# Google spreadsheet: Copy one row to a different Tab after inputting the word "Done"

Tags: import, google-sheets, range

I am trying to copy one row to another tab within the same Google Spreadsheet after I write the word "Done" in the first tab in column J. Any ideas?

I tried doing this myself using ImportRange but can't seem to get the formula correct. If it's not an importrange, please let me know what other formula would be correct for this purpose.

Here is the spreadsheet (feel free to edit):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d8wNc7XDcMfGomVkZPzBcE1Vz1YmCYMp_0mpyzDEQp4/edit#gid=0

Please note, I am not looking for a script. Any ideas and suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a query:

```
=query('All Data'!A:J,"select * where J='done' ")
```

Should form  dynamic link that repeats only the 'done' rows in a different sheet.